# missing folder from next.js folder structure using create-next-app

Tags: directory, next.js13

I have created next.js basic app using "npx create-next-app appname" command. But many of the folders are missing from the folder structure. For example (api, styles, pages) all these folders are missing.
[This is the screenshot of create-next-app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq8R6.png)

[This is the screenshot of command in terminal I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAh6t.png)

Answer (score 3):

The folders pages and styles are missing because you have selected the option "Yes" to "Use App Router", if you answer "No" to this option you will have these folders created automatically.